# Flutter Admob AppID use Android or iOS?

Tags: firebase, admob, flutter

When we make an AdMob app in the admob console, we have a choice of Android or iOS apps. That means 2 different IDs.

Which one should we use in the Flutter AdMob plugin?

```
FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about setting as follows?

```
import 'dart:io';

  FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(
    appId: Platform.isAndroid
        ? 'ca-app-pub-NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN~NNNNNNNNNN'
        : 'ca-app-pub-MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM~MMMMMMMMMM',
  );
```

If you dislike conditional operators you can set as follows.

```
import 'dart:io';

  var appId;
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    appId = 'ca-app-pub-NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN~NNNNNNNNNN';
  } else {
    appId = 'ca-app-pub-MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM~MMMMMMMMMM';
  }
  FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
```

Comment: That makes a ton of sense to me, but I wonder why there is no mention of it on the pubdart for the admob plugin? Was wondering if there is a reason not to do it this way?

Comment: Are not you satisfied with my answer?
I'm sorry. I did not understand what you wanted to know...=(

Comment: What happens if we use the Android AppId for the iOS App aswell?

Comment: Have you used if condition for this? or you found something else too?