# firebase_admob ios and android appid , adUnitId

Tags: flutter

am trying to use firebase_admob ads with flutter at ios and android

i saw that 
[Flutter Admob AppID use Android or iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021282/flutter-admob-appid-use-android-or-ios)
that show how to use two appId , that's good

but with adUnitId with every appID there two different

how to use two adUnitId with for each ios or android like appid

that code

```
BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
    print("BannerAd event is $event");
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's seems work with that  still searching

```
InterstitialAd myInterstitial = InterstitialAd(
  adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
      ? InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId
      : InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
    print("InterstitialAd event is $event");
  },
);
```